# getting index of list when click change location 

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I get the Index of city cliked and pass it to function Daily.js 
exemple when user change location to differnt city I want to change the Url 
in the list location 1 => url 1 
location2 => url 2 
...

```js
function Daily({ locationProps = 1, root }) {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const localization = useCallback(() => {
    if (root && cookies.get("location") !== undefined) {
      return cookies.get("location");
    }
    return locationProps;
  }, [locationProps, root]);
  
   const handleClick = event => {
    window.focus();
    notification.close(event.target.tag);
  };

  const openNav = () => {
    document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "100%";
  };

  const closeNav = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "0";
  };

  const _data = useRef(new Data(INDEX));  // -----> How to pass INDEX here !

  const getTimes = () => _data.current.getTimes();
  const times = useState(()=>getTimes());
```

```js
data.json 

location [
  liste of location 
], 
URL [
   list of url
]
```

Comment: ```const _data = useRef(new Data(1));``` if index=1 the function give me data from location 1

Comment: What's `INDEX` within `<Daily>` ? In other words, where is it supposed to be coming from ?

Comment: location [city1 ,2 ,3,4...] when user click city 3 for exemple get index of 3

Comment: ```function Locations({ closeNav, locations, locationsShort, weights }) {
  return (
    <div id="sidenav" className="sidenav">
      <a href="true" className="closebtn" onClick={e => closeNav(e)}>
        &times;
      </a>
      <ul>
        {locations.map((location, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              <Link
                className={`location-${weights[index]}`}
                to={`/${slugify(location, {
                  replacement: "-",

               
              >
                {locationsShort[index]}
              ```

Comment: From your code, looks like you have `location` stored locally and `localization` returns it. Is that accurate? It's hard to follow your code - `Locations` isn't even on your code above.

Comment: yes Now i try to get the index of location to pass it to New Data()

Comment: Are you wanting to get a specific location's index or all locations?

Comment: in sidenav I have liste of locations when user choose location number 1 I want to pass 1 to ```const _data = useRef(new Data(1));``` and when locations clicked is city 2 ```const _data = useRef(new Data(2));``` ....

Comment: `const selectedLocationIndex = localization.indexOf('yourLocation');`

`const _data = useRef(new Data(selectedLocationIndex));`

Comment: I get this error TypeError: localization.indexOf is not a function

Comment: Because `localization` is apparently not an array. What does `console.log(localization)` return?

Comment: console.log return () => {
    if (root && cookies.get("location") !== undefined) {
      return cookies.get("location");
    }

    return locationProps;
  }

Comment: ```console.table(locations);``` retur array with all locations

Comment: Post that array here

Comment: ```const locationpos  = locations.indexOf(locations[locationState]);```

Comment: ```cosole.log(locationspos)``` return the index of location

Comment: This is confusing - is this for a school project? Did someone else write it? Also, if `locationspos` returns the index, then why not use that? Finally, seeing as you're new on SO please review this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask